# Create PDF error script message | ReferenceError: row is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I cannot figure out why i am getting the error below:
[image]

This is the Google doc template, to be filled with informatio contained in google sheet (3rd screenshot, below.

The idea is to generate PDF for each row which have the check on TRUE.

```
function CreateBulkPDFs() {
  const DocFile = DriveApp.getFileById("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
  const DossTEMP = DriveApp.getFolderById("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB");
  const EmplacementPDF = DriveApp.getFolderById("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC");
  const CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ADMISSIBILITÉ  SÉLECTION");
  //const Data = CurrentSheet.getRangeList(['A1:D4', 'F1:H4']);
  const DATE = CurrentSheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  const FONCTION = CurrentSheet.getRange("C3").getValue();
  const UNITE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N4").getValue();
  const ANCIENNETE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N5").getValue();
  var NomMatr = CurrentSheet.getRange("A8:N" + CurrentSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    NomMatr.forEach(([check], i) => {
      if (check === true) {
      CreatePDF(DATE,row[6],row[7],FONCTION,UNITE,ANCIENNETE,"Appel d'intérêt_Comblement titulaire 4.05_" + row[6],DocFile,DossTEMP,EmplacementPDF);
      try {
        CurrentSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 8)).uncheck();
      }catch(err) {
    } 
  } 
});
}

function CreatePDF(DATE,NOM,MATRICULE,FONCTION,UNITE,ANCIENNETE,PDFName,DocFile,DossTEMP,EmplacementPDF) {
  const tempFile = DocFile.makeCopy(DossTEMP);
  const tempDocFile = DocumentApp.openById(tempFile.getId());
  const Body = tempDocFile.getBody();
  Body.replaceText("{DATE}", DATE);
  Body.replaceText("{NOM}", NOM);
  Body.replaceText("{MATRICULE}", MATRICULE);
  Body.replaceText("{FONCTION}", FONCTION);
  Body.replaceText("{UNITE}", UNITE);
  Body.replaceText("{ANCIENNETE}", ANCIENNETE);
  tempDocFile.saveAndClose();
  const PdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  EmplacementPDF.createFile(PdfContentBlob).setName(PDFName);//(NOM + "_" + MATRICULE)
  //FICHIERSTEMP.removeFile(tempFile);
}
```

[image]

Comment: In your situation, what values do you want to use at `NOM,MATRICULE` of `CreatePDF` function? Because from your error message, `row` is not declared. For example, when `NomMatr.forEach(([check], i) => {` is modified to `NomMatr.forEach((row, i) => {` or `NomMatr.forEach(([check, ...row], i) => {`, those are your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike: This code solved a part of the problem ! `NomMatr.forEach(([check, ...row], i) => {` | I'm now able to generate PDF. But an issue still ongoing, related to `NOM,MATRICULE`. In fact, I want to display on the generated PDF the name mentionned in cells `E8 - E9 - E10`. Matricule: cells `G8 - G9 - G10`. What do I need to modify in the code ?

Comment: thanks to you Tanaike, I modified my script and it's working!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the functional code

```
    function CreateBulkPDFs() {
  const DocFile = DriveApp.getFileById("AAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
  const DossTEMP = DriveApp.getFolderById("BBBBBBBBBB");
  const EmplacementPDF = DriveApp.getFolderById("DDDDDDDDDDD");
  const CurrentSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ADMISSIBILITÉ  SÉLECTION");
  //const Data = CurrentSheet.getRangeList(['A1:D4', 'F1:H4']);
  const DATE = CurrentSheet.getRange("E5").getValue();
  const FONCTION = CurrentSheet.getRange("C4").getValue();
  const UNITE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N4").getValue();
  const ANCIENNETE = CurrentSheet.getRange("N5").getValue();
  //const NOM = CurrentSheet.row[5].getValue();
  //const MATRICULE = CurrentSheet.row[7].getValue();
  var NomMatr = CurrentSheet.getRange("A8:N" + CurrentSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    NomMatr.forEach(([check, ...row], i) => {
      const NOM = row[3];
      const MATRICULE = row[5];
      if (check === true) {
      CreatePDF(DATE,NOM,MATRICULE,FONCTION,UNITE,ANCIENNETE,"Appel d'intérêt_Comblement titulaire 4.05_" + NOM,DocFile,DossTEMP,EmplacementPDF);
      try {
        CurrentSheet.getRange("A" + (i + 8)).uncheck();
      }catch(err) {
    } 
  } 
});
}
```